# regex returning null value

Tags: python, regex

I have wrote following code in my Vscode python file.

```
import  os
import  re
filecontent=[]
new_list=[]
"""Placeholder, change, rename, remove... """
for file in os.listdir("resources/"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join("resources/", file), "r") as files:
            filecontent = files.read()
            new_list.append(filecontent)
regex = re.compile(r'[\^======================$]*^Username:(\w+)')
for items in new_list:
    print(regex.findall(items))
```

And structure of my text file is

```
======================
Username:apple
email:apple@gmail.com
phonenumber:8129812891
address:kapan
======================
======================
Username:apple
email:apple@gmail.com
phonenumber:8129812891
address:kapan
======================
Username:apple
email:apple@gmail.com
phonenumber:9841898989
address:kapan
======================
Username:apple
email:apple@gmail.com
phonenumber:1923673645
address:kapan
======================
```

When i verify it in online regex checker. It works fine. But when i run it in my app it returns empty list.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mrlb.png
What is the wrong thing i am doing here?

Comment: In the online regex checker you are using the flags `gm`. But in your code you don't pass any flags to re.compile. Your use of $ and ^ will not work as expected if you don't compile the regex using the multiline flag. https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to match the `===` here. You can just search the username and return the result.

You can also remove your `re.compile()` and just run `re.findall(r'Username:\w+', items)`

---

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(re.findall(r'Username:(\w+)', data))
    print(re.findall(r'Username:\w+', data))


#['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']
#['Username:apple', 'Username:apple', 'Username:apple', 'Username:apple']
```